# Why headers of javax.servlet.http.Part in Spring Boot are either null or have same value with HttpServletRequest headers in multipart request?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, servlets

I have a **Client** Spring Boot project which sends a multipart request (actually uploads a picture) to a **Server** Spring Boot project.

this is the service of my **Client** Spring Boot project which sends the request:

```
@Service
public class MyService {

    @Autowired
    RestTemplate restTemplate;

    public String upload(MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
        String destinationUrl = "http://localhost:8081/upload";
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);
        headers.add(HttpHeaders.ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_ORIGIN, "*");
        headers.add(HttpHeaders.ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_METHODS, "PULL, POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
        headers.add(HttpHeaders.ACCESS_CONTROL_MAX_AGE, "3600");
        headers.add(HttpHeaders.ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_HEADERS, "x-requested-with");
        headers.add(HttpHeaders.ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_HEADERS, "Content-Type, api_key, Authorization");
        headers.add(HttpHeaders.ACCESS_CONTROL_EXPOSE_HEADERS, "Content-Disposition");
        // =========================================================================================
        // first part
        MultiValueMap<String, String> filePartMetadata = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
        ContentDisposition contentDisposition1 = createContentDisposition("form-data", "file", "Taoon.jpeg");
        filePartMetadata.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, contentDisposition1.toString());
        filePartMetadata.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE);
        filePartMetadata.add("content-transfer-encoding", "binary"); 
        HttpEntity<byte[]> filePartEntity;
        filePartEntity = new HttpEntity<>(file.getBytes(), filePartMetadata);
        // =========================================================================================
        // second part
        MultiValueMap<String, String> secondPartMetadata = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
        ContentDisposition contentDisposition2 = createContentDisposition("form-data", "fileId");
        secondPartMetadata.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, contentDisposition2.toString());
        HttpEntity<String> secondPartEntity = new HttpEntity<>("#675", secondPartMetadata);
        // =========================================================================================
        // third part
        MultiValueMap<String, String> thirdPartMetadata = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
        ContentDisposition contentDisposition3 = createContentDisposition("form-data", "title");
        thirdPartMetadata.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, contentDisposition3.toString());
        HttpEntity<String> thirdPartEntity = new HttpEntity<>("The Plague", thirdPartMetadata);
        // =========================================================================================
        // fourth part
        MultiValueMap<String, String> fourthPartMetadata = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
        ContentDisposition contentDisposition4 = createContentDisposition("form-data", "name");
        fourthPartMetadata.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, contentDisposition4.toString());
        HttpEntity<String> fourthPartEntity = new HttpEntity<>("albert camus's the plague", fourthPartMetadata);
        // =========================================================================================
        MultiValueMap<String, Object> bodyParts = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
        bodyParts.add("fiP", filePartEntity);
        bodyParts.add("sP", secondPartEntity);
        bodyParts.add("tP", thirdPartEntity);
        bodyParts.add("foP", fourthPartEntity);
        HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(bodyParts, headers);

        return restTemplate.postForEntity(destinationUrl, requestEntity, String.class).getBody();
    }

    private ContentDisposition createContentDisposition(String dispositionType, String contentDispositionName) {
        return ContentDisposition.builder(dispositionType)
                .name(contentDispositionName)
                .build();
    }

    private ContentDisposition createContentDisposition(String dispositionType,
                                                        String contentDispositionName, String contentDispositionFileName) {
        return ContentDisposition.builder(dispositionType)
                .name(contentDispositionName)
                .filename(contentDispositionFileName, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
                .build();
    }
```

now, in my **Server** Spring Boot project, I wrote this `Filter` to track and check the request that has been sent:

```
@WebFilter("/upload")
@Component
@Order(1)
public class MyFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;

        printHttpServletRequestHeaders(httpServletRequest);

        Collection<Part> parts = httpServletRequest.getParts();
        parts.forEach(part -> {
            System.out.println("========================================");
            System.out.println("part size:\t" + part.getSize());
            System.out.println("the part content type:\t" + part.getContentType());
            System.out.println("the part name:\t" + part.getName());
            System.out.println("the part submitted file name:\t" + part.getSubmittedFileName());

            if (!part.getContentType().equals(MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE)) {
                System.out.print("body of the part:\t");
                try {
                    byte[] bytes = part.getInputStream().readAllBytes();
                    String body = new String(bytes);
                    System.out.println(body);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            }

            Collection<String> headerNames = part.getHeaderNames();
            System.out.println("the part's headers:");
            headerNames.forEach(headerName -> {
                System.out.println("\t" + headerName + " (header) --> " + httpServletRequest.getHeader(headerName));
            });
            System.out.println("========================================");
        });

        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    private void printHttpServletRequestHeaders(HttpServletRequest request) {
        Iterator<String> headersNameIterator = request.getHeaderNames().asIterator();
        while (headersNameIterator.hasNext()) {
            String headerName = headersNameIterator.next();
            System.out.println(headerName + ":" + request.getHeader(headerName));
        }
    }
}
```

and this is the result of execution of my `Filter` and actually the request which I received in my Server Spring Boot project:

```
accept:text/plain, application/json, application/*+json, */*
content-type:multipart/form-data;boundary=1QIvQU7agC_ATe8c6BEqvgKMSjyk_4uVV5IKSu
access-control-allow-origin:*
access-control-allow-methods:PULL, POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE
access-control-max-age:3600
access-control-allow-headers:x-requested-with
access-control-expose-headers:Content-Disposition
user-agent:Java/11.0.16.1
host:localhost:8081
connection:keep-alive
content-length:2848
========================================
part size:  2107
the part content type:  image/jpeg
the part name:  file
the part submitted file name:   Taoon.jpeg
the part's headers:
    content-disposition (header) --> null
    content-type (header) --> multipart/form-data;boundary=1QIvQU7agC_ATe8c6BEqvgKMSjyk_4uVV5IKSu
    content-transfer-encoding (header) --> null
    content-length (header) --> 2848
========================================
========================================
part size:  4
the part content type:  text/plain;charset=UTF-8
the part name:  fileId
the part submitted file name:   null
body of the part:   #675
the part's headers:
    content-disposition (header) --> null
    content-type (header) --> multipart/form-data;boundary=1QIvQU7agC_ATe8c6BEqvgKMSjyk_4uVV5IKSu
    content-length (header) --> 2848
========================================
========================================
part size:  10
the part content type:  text/plain;charset=UTF-8
the part name:  title
the part submitted file name:   null
body of the part:   The Plague
the part's headers:
    content-disposition (header) --> null
    content-type (header) --> multipart/form-data;boundary=1QIvQU7agC_ATe8c6BEqvgKMSjyk_4uVV5IKSu
    content-length (header) --> 2848
========================================
========================================
part size:  25
the part content type:  text/plain;charset=UTF-8
the part name:  name
the part submitted file name:   null
body of the part:   albert camus's the plague
the part's headers:
    content-disposition (header) --> null
    content-type (header) --> multipart/form-data;boundary=1QIvQU7agC_ATe8c6BEqvgKMSjyk_4uVV5IKSu
    content-length (header) --> 2848
========================================
```

now, my question is why Part's headers like `content-disposition` and `content-transfer-encoding` are null? what is wrong in my **Server** code that I receive these two header null?

actually all of the Part's header are either null or have same value as the HttpServletRequest's headers value. why?

Thank you. sorry for my bad english.

***PS***: in some question, someone mentioned that it may be relate to CORS and I set CORS header in my server project but I still receive them null.

Comment: This isn't really anything Spring related in here, it is a web filter and thus is bound to the Servlet container handling your request. I would also say your code is wrong as you are trying to get the part header from the `HttpServletRequest` and not the `Part`. Looks like the error is in your own code. You should be doing `part.getHeader` not `httpServletRequest.getHeader` in the for loop.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thank You So much sir. yes. I was wrong on getting headers from httpServletRequest. you solved my problem. thank you again.